# What is the purpose of safeToDelete.tmp file in the temp dir in Apache Tomcat 8.5.40?

Tags: tomcat8, temp

I am using Apache Tomcat 8.5.40 and there is a temp directory and safeToDelete.tmp file 0KB in it. What is this file used for?

Comment: It tells you that that directory is safe to delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a *marker file* used to ensure that the directory gets created by file archive creator/extractor programs that may otherwise skip empty directories.